# Firebase test lab - Supply Robo script from CI or command line?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am using Firebase test labs along with Jenkins to run a Robo test after each build of my Android app. Currently I use a Yaml file to setup all the configurations I need. I supply a username and password using the Robo Directives. However, I now want to supply a Robo Script that controls the sign in process a little bit more than just supplying the login details. I have made the script in Android studio, but I don't see anywhere in the documentation that allows me to supply the location of the Robo Script from the Yaml file or command line, does anyone know if this is possible?

I have tried the documentation and various links from here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is available today in beta, but not as a full release.  You can use the `--robo-script` flag to specify a script to upload when using

```
gcloud beta firebase test android run
```

It is not available in the release version:

```
gcloud firebase test android run
```

After some time in beta, new features will be promoted to full release.  [See the CLI docs for the beta version here.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firebase/test/android/run)

Comment: Asking around internally, it seems this feature was worked on, but for some reason isn't available in gcloud yet.  Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Much appreciated.

Comment: Updated the answer - use `gcloud beta` instead.

Comment: is there a way to run only script test, but not random ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was looking for the same thing and I find it :
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firebase/test/android/run#--robo-script

Using like this

```
gcloud firebase test android run --app app-release.apk --robo-script script.json
```